# Echoing a name from session php

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I'm a student and I'm making a quiz using php and mysql, my problem is I'm trying to echo a name on the results page but it doesn't work.

My first page is an index page where I create a form which gets the users name which I send to my quiz.php page.

```
<form method="post" action="quiz.php"> 
    <img src="pictures/indeximage.jpg" alt="horrormovies" width="1024" height="640">
    <p> 
        Please Enter Your Name
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="name"> 
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start"> 
</form>
```

on my quiz.php page i put make a variable and put it in a session

```
<?php
    //start session
    session_start();
    $var_name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $_SESSION['ses_name']=$var_name;
?>
```

On my results page I have this

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $var_name=$_SESSION['ses_name'];

?>
<p>
    Thank you for taking the quiz  <?php echo $var_name; ?>.
</p>
```

Comment: have you set the session variable

Comment: Call `quiz.php?name=YOUR_QUIZ_NAME` and then go to result page. You should see the result.

Comment: check var_dump($_SESSION) first. what comes inside it?

Comment: I've just tried your code and it works fine as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Use isset for assign value in session variable. for good practice.**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  //start session
  session_start();
  $var_name=$_REQUEST['name'];
  $_SESSION['ses_name']=$var_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> quiz.php

```
 session_start();
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
      $_SESSION['ses_name']=$_REQUEST['name'];
    }
```

Try this code :-

> results page

```
    <?php
    //start session
    session_start();
    if(!empty($_SESSION['ses_name']))
    {
    ?>
    <p>Thank you for taking the quiz  <?php echo $_SESSION['ses_name']; ?>.</p>
    <?php
    }
    else{
    echo 'session not set ';die;
    }
    ?>
```